# Soundex/Metaphone for phonegap on android

Tags: android, sql, cordova, soundex

I need to make sql-searches using something like: `soundex` or `metaphone` for `android` over `phonegap`.

But neither `soundex` nor `metaphone` works.

Example:
    `SELECT * FROM customers WHERE soundex(surname) = soundex('Mayer');`

This brings me the message, that `soundex` isn't known.

Does anybody know how I can use `soundex` or something like `soundex` with `phonegap` (`android`)?

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to create the soundex/metaphone index in your phone gap code.  In Javascript you could use the [clj-fuzzy library](http://yomguithereal.github.io/clj-fuzzy/javascript.html#double_metaphone).

1. Add a soundex/metaphone column to your `customers` table.
2. When you insert/update the record, calculate the soundex/metaphone index in Javascript, and insert/update that value,
   too.
3. When executing a search, you can calculate the soundex/metaphone index of the search criteria, and check its equality against the
   soundex/metaphone column.

So the insert might look like:

`insert into customers (surname, surname_metaphone)
values ('Smith', 'SM0')`

And the select like:

`select * from customers where surname_metaphone = 'SM0'`